# Using "seq", If one column is equal to 5, continue the other column

Tags: text-processing, awk, seq

For example, I want to start from the far right column, and once that reaches 5, continue the count from the second farthest column.

```
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.0.0.2
0.0.0.3
0.0.0.4
0.0.0.5
0.0.1.5
0.0.2.5
0.0.3.5
0.0.4.5
0.0.5.5
0.1.5.5
0.2.5.5
0.3.5.5
0.4.5.5
0.5.5.5
1.5.5.5
2.5.5.5
3.5.5.5
4.5.5.5
5.5.5.5
```

So far, I was thinking of using:

```
for i in $(seq 0 5); do echo "0.0.0.$i"; done
```

and once `i == 5`, then well set `i=0`, and move the echo to the third position.

Comment: @thanasisp Yes, the ending would remain to the max value it reached. The previous user did offer a printf that does work nicely, but I'm trying to get a seq to work

Comment: It's a different thing to print the combinations or permutations from what you describe here. [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/622844/edit) your question and make the question clear, with a correct output.

Comment: @thanasisp I thought I made that quite clear by showing it ends of at 5.5.5.5 and not any values being changed

Comment: Shouldn't the title be changed in "...If one column is equal to 5, ..." ?

Comment: Does it have to be a shell script using `seq`, or are dedicated text-processing tools like `awk` also an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using loop:

```
{
  for i in $(seq 0 5); do echo "0.0.0.$i"   ; done;
  for j in $(seq 1 5); do echo "0.0.$j.$i"  ; done;
  for k in $(seq 1 5); do echo "0.$k.$j.$i" ; done;
  for l in $(seq 1 5); do echo "$l.$k.$j.$i"; done;
}
```

Using `awk` and more flexible to increase the repeat time as well as adjustable number of fields from the single line input:

```
awk -F"." -v OFS="." -v repeat=5 '
{ print $0;
  for(c=NF; c>=1; c--){
      for (i=1; i<=repeat; i++) { $c=i ; print $0; };
  };
}' <<<'0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use seq four different times ?

Comment: Really nice awk script!

Comment: @EdMorton thank you, I'm happy hearing this from you who is expert in awk field   :  )